# Are different boto3 versions better suited for different Python versions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

According to the boto3 documentation, boto3 is backwards compatible with Python 2.7 & Python 3. I've been running into a few issues that some Python versions weren't completely compatible with certain versions of boto3.

I was wondering if there is:

- a boto3 version that is best suited for Python 2.7
- a boto3 version that is best suited for Python 3.6
- a boto3 version that is best suited for Python 3.7
- or if the latest boto3 version should technically work for all versions of Python?

I've read through the boto3 documentation and repository to see if any information is given on this, but could not find any relative information other than it should be compatible to all versions.

Comment: What compatibility issues were you experiencing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you always want the latest version of Boto3 so you will have access to all the latest Amazon services and features.